# Converting HTML to PDF using PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

Is it possible to convert a HTML page to PDF using PHP, and if so, how can it be done?

Specifically, the page is an invoice generated dynamically. So I would like it loaded using:

```
http://example.com/invoices/3333
```

And the HTML output would have to be converted to PDF.

Any good libraries that do this will be fine.

Comment: GrabzIt has a free PHP Library for converting HTML to PDF: http://grabz.it/html-to-pdf-image-api.aspx

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you wish to ***create*** a pdf from php, pdflib will help you (as some others suggested).

Else, if you want to ***convert*** an HTML page to PDF via PHP, you'll find a little trouble outta here.. For 3 years I've been trying to do it as best as I can.

So, the options I know are:

[DOMPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) : php class that wraps the html and builds the pdf. Works good, customizable (if you know php), based on pdflib, if I remember right it takes even some CSS. Bad news: slow when the html is big or complex.

[HTML2PS](http://user.it.uu.se/~jan/html2ps.html): same as DOMPDF, but this one converts first to a .ps (ghostscript) file, then, to whatever format you need (pdf, jpg, png). For me is little better than dompdf, but has the same *speed problem*.. but, better compatibility with CSS.

Those two are php classes, but if you can install some software on the server, and access it throught passthru() or system(), give a look to these too:

[wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org): based on webkit (safari's wrapper), is really fast and powerful.. seems like  this is the best one (atm) for converting html pages to pdf on the fly; taking only 2 seconds for a 3 page xHTML document with CSS2. It is a recent project, anyway, the google.code page is often updated.

[htmldoc](https://michaelrsweet.github.io/htmldoc/) : This one is a tank, it never really stops/crashes.. the project looks dead since 2007, but anyway if you don't need CSS compatibility this can be nice for you.

Comment: Daniel, which one is the best for CSS then? WkHTMLToPdf?

Comment: Yes, actually.
we are triyn to use firefox too (with a command line addon by torisugary), becose, you know, nothing will take css better then a browser. wkhtmltopdf run on safari, so actually is the best, imho.
I hope that mozilla will do something like it with gecko soon

Comment: Dan, can you call wkhtml through php? It seems like it needs to be called using shell manually

Comment: Sure, passthru() should work.
something like passthru('wkhtmltopdf_version.sh http://yourhtmlpage.html yourpdf.pdf' $return); would work well if php and apache permissions settings allow that. Tried on a windows machine, works good.

Comment: Oh, sorry i forget a thing: for unix-like systems there is actual a problem with the display of wkhtml - give a look at here if is your case:
http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=3
otherise on windows system, you'll need to compile it under apache maybe (depends on your settings)

Comment: wkhtmltopdf has worked the best and with the least setup steps in my experience.

Comment: Wkhtmltopdf is awesome and can convert exact html+css to pdf

Comment: But they all fail with flexbox and grid, amirite?

Comment: wkhtmltopdf is no longer maintained which is a problem, because the underlying QT library it uses requires the outdated OpenSSL 1.0, which is getting harder and harder to install.

Comment: @LajosMészáros any alternative to wkhtmltopdf thast works nowaday?

Comment: @Strae the one that I got the furthest with nowadays is Dompdf, but it needs some extra rounds with adding your own font to have utf-8 support - which I yet to investigate myself too - and I also had some issues with the pages being zoomed in too much. So it's not perfect out of the box, but I see the possibility in it.