# Direct Print webpage in PDF file

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, printing, directshow

In my site i m fetching my mysql data by using PHP. I want open that data in pdf file when i click pdf print button is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you want a high quality professional product to do that. You want [Prince XML](http://www.princexml.com/)

If you are looking into some open source tool to achieve something similar. You can look into [this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733219/converting-html-to-pdf-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

You could prepare static PDF form file, that just fill it in with values using PHP's [FDF module](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.fdf.php).

Answer (score 0):

It depends which platform are you using. This would be an easy job if you are using Groovy on grails. There are plugins which facilitate pdf reporting like the jasper-plugin.

Luis

Answer (score 0):

Check out [jsPDF](http://code.google.com/p/jspdf/), an open-source library for generating PDF documents using nothing but JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can process the data with Apache FOP after transforming it to XML. (http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/).

If your page is template based, you may create a template which produces xml output and process that. You'll have extremely well contol over the pdf construction. The tradeoff is that it is not a "plug this in and will work" solution, but I've done that and once its set up, works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

I've used TCPDF in the past, it's a little kludgy but can definitely get the job done. (http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=tcpdf)

Answer (score 0):

The FPDF module in PHP is simple enough to get the data together. It is a safe option since you know what data you are passing out to the PDF engine. There are some streaming pdf options which can take in a bunch of html and then output that to pdf however they can get it quite wrong without you knowing.

Answer (score 0):

I used, on Linux machines, [WKHTMLTOIMAGE/WKHTMLTOPDF](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) a number of times, on many projects. It workes like a charm, easy to use, just a script that you run.