# convert html to pdf output result UTF-8(for php)

Tags: html, pdf

How to convert html to pdf.Show outupt result UTF-8.I use html2pdf libary.This libary don't support utf-8.Please tell me which libaries i use and how to solve this probleam.

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733219/converting-html-to-pdf-using-php

Comment: True, but this question is specific about Unicode support.

Comment: It seems the bigger problem is converting to PDF at all, so the OP should at least clarify a few requirements/possibilities he has and/or specify a library he's using. If the way he's doing it doesn't support UTF-8, that should be a more specific question.

Comment: Agreed. 
@meme - please edit your question and make it more detailed (read comment above)

Answer (score 0):

open office can open HTML in Unicode (I have good experience with Hebrew document) and export them as pdf.

Perhaps you can use the [open office utility library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ooolib/), which feature:

> - Ability to create OpenOffice.org Calc Documents
> - Ability to create OpenOffice.org Writer Documents
> - Example programs that use the Perl Module
> - Documentation for using ooolib and the API