# How to save text in php as a pdf file?

Tags: php, text, pdf-generation, url-shortener

I have textarea in my site(link shortening site) i want to user enter some kind of text and as a return i will give(shorten link) a pdf file which user can download.How can i do that with php do i need extra library or default php libraries are capable of doing that?(i am working on windows machine by the way)(site using php mysql apache latest versions)

Comment: This dupe will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733219/converting-html-to-pdf-using-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This should help you](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php)

And I found [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/) as well. :)

But I think the first solution will suit it more because it is not from a third party

Comment: i am using aptana studio as php ide but i dont know how to make this library work.