# Autoprint PDF script on php or javascript

Tags: php, javascript, pdf, printing

I want to build a page that will automatically print a pdf document. For example I can call mypage.html?doc=my.pdf and it will print my.pdf file.

How I can do it using javascript or php?

Vladimir

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting HTML to PDF using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733219/converting-html-to-pdf-using-php)

Comment: You mean, as in physically print on paper? Urgh!

Comment: This is not exactly the same, but it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167995/generate-a-pdf-that-automatically-prints/6168091#6168091

Comment: You can't make the browser immediately offer the user the option of printing a PDF file, but you can output a PDF using a method provided by one of the users above. From there the user can opt to click the print button on their own (or choose to open/save the PDF depending on the headers you use). But to directly answer your question, there's no way to do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest you can get to what you want is to embed an iframe containing the PDF in an HTML page, then call `window.print` when the iframe has loaded.

```
...
<iframe src="path/to/file.pdf" onload="window.print()"></iframe>
...
```

This will open the standard print dialog on most browsers.