# Call Adobe Reader PDF print dialog from a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, acrobat, mpdf

Please help, I've been looking for hours but I can't find a definitive answer... On my web app a jQuery dialog pops up with a PDF loaded within an iframe. If possible I need the user to be able to click the "print" button (on jQuery UI modal dialog) which then brings up the Adobe Reader print dialog for them to print the PDF. I know they can hover over the PDF to show the toolbar but this is not always ideal for the computer illiterate. Tried the usual things like window.print() etc and also looking into PDF "open parameters" to no avail.

http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf

I've also tried embedding the PDF and using window.print() and print preview but the PDF doesn't show on the preview screen.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167995/generate-a-pdf-that-automatically-prints/6168091#6168091

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this one, I keep getting an error "print is not a function"

Comment: It does not work in all combinations of browsers and PDF readers...

Comment: Hmm seems that it work on IE but not FF, Chrome etc. Still looking.....

Comment: It's messy and possibly a strain on the server, but for now when the user clicks "print" I'm going to reload the PDF into the iframe with Javascript embedded into the PDF to open the print dialog hehe

Comment: If you are going to do that then at least try using linearized pdfs.