# Open print dialog when pdf stream open in new tab

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, pdf

Using MVC3, and have a form that post data that contains what report to generate as pdf from report server to controller. My controller return `File(pdfstream, "application/pdf")` and the pdf opens in new tab. Is there any way to make the browser display print dialog when the tab with the pdf opens?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate a PDF that automatically prints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167995/generate-a-pdf-that-automatically-prints)

Comment: It does seem to be a duplicate of [Generate a PDF that automatically prints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167995/generate-a-pdf-that-automatically-prints)