# Opened .pdf in new browser window immediately shows print settings, how to fix this?

Tags: html, pdf, browser, printing

I have made a website and have an annoying problem.

If a visitor clicks on a link to a .pdf file, it opens in a new window as I specified in the code with target="_blank". When the .pdf opens, the print settings immediatly pop up, as if the user clicked on the 'print' button in his browser .pdf viewer.

How do I solve this? The print settings must not popup immediately. I don't think it is specified in my code, nor do I think it is a browser setting, because it only happens on my own website and not on other sites.

```
<h2>PDF File</h2>
<?php 
if ($row_Recordset['file'] != NULL) 
{ ?>
<a class="file_link" href="../files/<?php echo $row_Recordset['file']; ?>" target="_blank"><img src="../img/pdf.gif" width="40" height="40" alt="PDF File" />PDF File </a>
<?php 
}
else
{
     echo "<p>No file.</p>";
}
?>
```

The css contains the following:

```
.file_link { color: black; }
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be because your PDF files have an "open action" that invokes this dialog when the file is opened. Check this question and its answers for details: [Generate a pdf that automatically prints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167995/generate-a-pdf-that-automatically-prints)