# Silently tracking pdf openings

Tags: javascript, flash, pdf

Is it possible either via .js or flash to silently be alerted when a .pdf is opened? Further is it possible to set (flash) cookies to enable tracking, again with no user notification?

I appreciate tracking only works with an internet connection, and a .pdf reader that supports script execution. This is not intended to be bulletproof.

I am not looking for a DRM solution, just a way to silently track if a .pdf is opened on more than 1 PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Adobe Javascript Scripting Guide](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/sdk/AcroJSGuide.pdf), you can invoke a SOAP Web Service method from a JavaScript action in a PDF File. You can then create a JavaScript action that calls a web service and set it to the OpenAction event of the Catalog dictionary, this event will be called when the file is opened. 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6168091/501196) is another question where I also recommended using the OpenAction event.