# wait until pdf created in new window before printing

Tags: javascript

I have a web program that dynamically creates a pdf, when a user
clicks on the print command in a data grid view, the pdf is created
in the page printpdf.aspx. and then the following code is executed:

```
function printpdf() 
{
    var printWindow = window.open('printpdf.aspx', '', 'height=100,width=200');            
    checkLoad();
    printWindow.focus();
    printWindow.print();
    printWindow.close();      
}
```

this code is being executed and I get a print dialog box and the form
closes on either ok or cancel, however the pdf is not yet generated
when this code is triggered. I need a way to wait for page load. or a
timer function that would work. I am also using this in multiple
browsers. I have tried a timer function with no luck and the onload
function.

```
checkLoad();
function checkLoad() 
{
    if (printWindow.onLoad) 
    {
        printWindow.focus();
        window.print();
        window.close();
    } 
    else 
    {
        setTimeout('checkLoad();', 1000)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this proper is to add a javascript to the pdf itself telling the pdf to print itself.

You can then load that pdf into a hidden iFrame which you need to clear onbeforeunload to not print again if the user reloads the page with the iFrame.

I have used this method successfully for more than 10 years.

[Generate a PDF that automatically prints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167995/generate-a-pdf-that-automatically-prints)