# Printing a PDF in an iframe using JavaScript in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, object, pdf, printing

I was wondering if it is possible to print the data of an object tag in html? For example I have an object like this:

```
<object id="myObject" data="myPDF.pdf"></object>
```

I have a PDF embedded in the object tag. I need to be able to print the PDF using a JavaScript function in Firefox. Placing the PDF in an iframe and printing does not work as Firefox will not let you access the frame's contents. Neither does using:

```
myObject.contentWindow.print();
```

or

```
document.getElementById("myObject").print();
```

Does anyone have any other suggestions? I am trying to figure out a way of printing just the data of the object (i.e. the PDF file) but have not found a solution so far. Using an iframe works for chrome and using an embed tag works for Internet Explorer, but I cannot find anything that will work in Firefox. Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print PDF directly from JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239513/print-pdf-directly-from-javascript)

Comment: No I stated in my question that the method in that question did not work for me. When I try using: document.getElementById("myObject").print(); the console says the method does not exist.

Comment: @Celt The second statement is complete wrong, because `document.getElementById("myObject")` returns a dom object (a representation of memory).

Comment: Hmm I didn't realise that, is there a way of accessing the object and then calling the a print() function?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6168091/501196

Comment: Thanks but that does not work in FF either, the console says the print() method does not exist..

Comment: @Celt I think it isn't possible, because the pdf file will be opend by the pdf plugin. For the browser itself are the data unknown and not convertable.

Comment: I was having that problem in IE but when I set the type to application/pdf the printing worked fine, nothing I have tried will work for FF though.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in firefox, not sure if it has been fixed: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=911444

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately as @yms said in the comments this is a bug in Firefox and there is no workaround for it yet. You can read the bug report [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=911444). There does not seem to be any progress on a fix but I will update this answer as soon as I hear of one.

Comment: No still has not been resolved as far as I know. I have just given up on it and am waiting for the bug fix from Mozilla.