# How to save a page as pdf in php

Tags: php

Does anyone know how I can save a page as pdf in php?

Example:
I have a page that is able to catch the users signature. Now I would like to create a button on the page that will convert the page into pdf so that the file can be saved to a folder.

Below you can see what the signature page looks like:
[image]

Comment: I guess you want to capture the screen or convert html to pdf. isn't it?

Comment: @AVD:I would like to convert the html into pdf, but somehow I want the signature could saved in the pdf like the one showing above (the signature is not in the picture format, it's generated by the javascript)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a number of PHP PDF API and tools which convert or wrap up html content including drawings, links and images etc.

A very good thread from StackOverflow :

1. [Convert HTML to PDF using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733219/converting-html-to-pdf-using-php)

Comment: Second link does not work anymore, for those who see this answer after me

Answer (score 5):

TCPDF can output PDF's from html: http://www.tcpdf.org/

If you need to use more advanced html you can use WKHTMLTOPDF: http://wkhtmltopdf.org/

Comment: I know this is old, but I have been using TCPDF for several years for some large clients and it has not failed me yet. Simple and fast!