# Print webpage as PDF in PHP

Tags: php, pdf-generation

I am newbie to php.

I have developed small application in PHP. Now I have few label controls in one webpage inside form. that i want to save in pdf. Is there any tool like itextsharp (In ASp.net), where I can export one panel or form to pdf. (By rendering)

I checked fpdf and other. In that we can print text. My label data is coming from MYSQL.

Any suggestion.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495509/how-to-save-a-page-into-pdf-in-php check this url

Comment: or see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733219/converting-html-to-pdf-using-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest mpdf. I'ts very simple, you can create your html as string and render it as pdf.

```
require_once("mpdf/mpdf.php");
$html = "<p>Hello World</p>";

$mpdf = new mPDF('c', 'A4');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
print $mpdf->Output();
```