# Can i Change an Image Dynamically with a number and then Print it to a PDF

Tags: javascript, php, html, image, pdf

I would like to ask for some help and i do apologize if my questions are too simple, i just can not figure out the right way to do it. I have 3 questions.

I am working on a project that has starts with an HTML form that takes several Variables in a PHP Session, runs 3 different calculators in the server and produces 4 numbers (As percents).
1- I want to take those answers (Percents) and Manipulate 4 graphs/images/plots that are basically a 10*10 Matrix (100 dots) of "Green" dots and change the dots to "Red" based on the answers.
After that it takes it to an HTML form that gets converted to a PDF.
This is a link to an example of the plot: http://web.cs.dal.ca/~mufti/sdm2/forms/mplot.pdf

2- Which format should i save the image in? (Should i use SVG)

3- What is the best way to convert an HTML to PDF?

I will deeply appreciate any guidance.

Note: I am not an expert developer, i know how to program in HTML, CSS, PHP and some basic knowledge in Javascript.

Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your response. I read the tutorials and know how to code, i just said that i am not an expert.

Comment: sorry, ignore my comment. I read it too fast!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone has already answered some good ways to transform HTML in PDF.
Once you have your image, you can use some of these libraries to convert.

[Converting HTML to PDF using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733219/converting-html-to-pdf-using-php)

About how to manipulate your image. I suggest [ImageMagick for PHP](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php#php). It's very very easy to learn and perfect for wat you need! You can save your image in the format you want (PNG or JPEG is ok)

You probably don't need to manipulate images... Just draw the grid dynamically with PHP.