# Print html table in pdf , many pdf to be generated

Tags: php, html, pdf

I have a page that is generated using data from a database into a table format.
Each result of a student is displayed on a page so that when printed on a printer, each result is printed on a page. I need now to generate a pdf for each student. How can I add code to generate the pdf, using the name of the student?

Thanks in advance.

```
<body>
   <?php
      $grade=7;
      require 'GetStudentNames.php';  
      while ($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {  ?>
   <P style="page-break-before: always"> 
   <table margin-top="70px"  width="100%">
      <tr>
         <td rowspan="2"><img src="logo.PNG"  alt="logo"></td>
         <td style="text-align:center" rowspan="1">
            <h2>xyz School</h2>
         </td>
      <tr>
         <td rowspan="1" style="text-align: center; ">
            <h3 style="text-decoration: underline ;text-align:center">Student Report Sheet - First Term 2021</h3>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   <?php echo '<br><table width="100%"><th width="50%">Student Name: '.@$row1["name"].'   '.@$row1["firstname"].'</th>';
      echo '</td>';
      require 'db.php';
      $sql = "select subject from results where SN = '".@$row1["sn"]."' order by listorder";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);
      $count=1;
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo '<tr class="oneSubj"><td class="oneSubj">'. $count.'.  '.@$row["subject"].'</td>
         
          </tr>';
          $count++;
      }?>
   </table>
   <br>
   <table style="width: 100%">
      <th style="width:25%">Absences..................</th>
      <br>
      <h5 style="text-decoration: underline ;text-align:center">Special Mention</h5>
   </table>
   <?php }?>
</body>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/733326/13231904

Comment: $sql = "SELECT *  from test ";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);      
    $row= mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
   
   
 header("Content-type: application/pdf");
    echo $row["im"];

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping, indeed veryhelpful, will read into it in time. I could use the above code working on PC but not loading on cellphones.